# How can I connect to a sqlite3 db using pyodbc and unixODBC?

Tags: sqlite, pyodbc, unixodbc

I can't figure out how to connect to a sqlite db using pyodbc. I have a DSN set up and can connect to it via isql without problems.

```
isql -v TEST
```

works like a charm, However

```
import pyodbc
pyodbc.connect('DSN=TEST')
```

Gives the following error message:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnectW)')
```

I also tried a great amount of permutations of the connection strings in the examples at https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/GettingStarted to no avail.

```
pyodbc.dataSources()
```

Does list the dsn I'm trying to connect to with the value holding the path to libsqlite3odbc.so

I assume I am missing something obvious, but I can't figure out what...

EDIT: Using unixODBC 2.3.0, python 2.7.1, sqliteodbc 0.88 and pyodbc 2.1.8
EDIT: The reason I want to use pyodbc is for portability to Windows and MS Access

Answer (score 0):

Just to check what is being passed to the driver manager, turn on ODBC tracing, in your odbcinst,ini file add

```
[ODBC]
Trace = Yes
TraceFile = /tmp/sql.log
```

Then run the app again and see what is being passed to the SQLConnect or SQLDriverConnect call.